# WP add_image_size binding to different post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I have maked site on WP. There are two slider-bars and some sections with img. Resolutions of this img are different.

I want ( need ) to use  add_image_size function to crop image for my tasks, but how I can bind func. add_image_size with imgs for one of the sections / slide-bars? I don't understand, how i must declare that thumbnail for post (for ex.) must be cropped by add_image_size. Sorry, may be for this is stupid question

Comment: Can you show any effort on your part? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will declare a new image size in your functions.php, something like:

```
add_image_size( '1280-thumb', 1280 );//1280px wide, free high
```

and then call that image size wherever you need it. So what you need to do is create as many image sizes as you need and then call each specific size in each sidebar or anywhere else on your site where those images might be needed.
You could limit when these thumbnails are created based on the post type they are uploaded to for example with something like this:

```
if( get_post_type() == ‘your_post_type’ ) {
    add_image_size( '1280-thumb', 1280 );//1280px wide, free high
}
```

This will only create the ‘1280-thumb’ for images uploaded directly to posts belonging to a custom post type named ‘your_custom_post_type’.

Comment: I declared img sizes in functions.php before creating posts types, and after creating posts types i use if with checking post type. It does not work. What i have maked wrong?

Comment: Remember this will only work for images you upload after you set up the IF condition, everything uploaded prior to it will remain as it was